# Unassign function from mouse button 8 and button 9 on ubuntu 19.10

Tags: mouse, configuration, logitech, button

I have mouse Logitech M590 with some extra buttons. By default buttons 8 and 9 works as "back" and "forward". I want to give them different functionality. A followed the last answer in this thread [How can I assign actions to all my mouse buttons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19569/how-can-i-assign-actions-to-all-my-mouse-buttons). I installed btnx daemon (I had to compile it on 18.04, it would not compile on 19.10). Then in btnx-config I assigned a new function - "zoom-out" and "zoom in" to buttons 8 and 9. But now one button has two functions, it is zooming in and going forward at the same time. I want them to have only one function which I assigned them in btnx-config.

How can I disable the default behavior of these buttons? I don't want to disable them completely, I still want to be able to assign them functions through btnx-config.

Comment: Related question https://superuser.com/q/1519680/490855

Answer (score 2):

I advice you to use Xbindkeys utility instead. You can find a nice guide [here](https://blog.hanschen.org/2009/10/13/mouse-shortcuts-with-xbindkeys/).

In short:

1. Install `xbindkeys`, preferably through your package manager.
2. You can create a default configuration file with the command:

   ```
   xbindkeys --defaults > $HOME/.xbindkeysrc
   ```
3. Open `~/.xbindkeysrc` in your your favorite text editor. If you can’t find it, make sure you have *Show hidden files* enabled.
4. Paste something like this on bottom of the file:

   ```
   # Back
   "xte 'keydown Alt_L' 'key Left' 'keyup Alt_L'"
    b:8

   # Forward
   "xte 'keydown Alt_L' 'key Right' 'keyup Alt_L'"
     b:9
   ```

   Here you can set any actions you want, in lines which start from `xte` command. Just replace buttons like <kbd>Alt_L</kbd> and <kbd>Left/Right</kbd> to get hotkeys that you want.

   `b8` and `b9` are codes for additional mouse buttons -- these are standart, but you can find codes for yours with `xbindkeys -k` command in terminal.

---

Also I suggest you to give a try to [Easystroke](https://github.com/thjaeger/easystroke/wiki) utility, which has a lot of functionality for mouse gestures (including additional buttons), but it requires more digging :)

As for me, I wanted my additional mouse button to act as a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, and I found a perfect guide [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2154356&p=12691359#post12691359), in the 5<sup>th</sup> post.

Currently my mouse setting is:

<kbd>additional button</kbd> + <kbd>middle click</kbd> → copy,
           + <kbd>right click</kbd> → paste,
           + <kbd>wheel scrolling</kbd> → zooming,
           + <kbd>left click</kbd> → select multiple files in file manager.

Let me know, if you'll need help on how to set something similar in Easystroke :)

Comment: I can attest `xbindkeys` works great for my Logitech MX Master mouse to assign thumb button (`b:10`) to keyboard `Enter` key.

Answer (score 0):

I found Autokey a useful tool to reassign functionality of keyboard keys, and it also has support for the mouse, see https://askubuntu.com/a/911195/854911